# Magento product URL with and without category

Tags: php, .htaccess, magento, magento2

I have removed the category from the product URL by overriding `getUrlPath` method in `CategoryUrlPathGenerator` using a module and is working fine. But now I need to show the product page on both with and without category in URL. Is there a way I could achieve this? Below is the code in `getUrlPath`.

```
public function getUrlPath($category, $parentCategory = null)
    {
        if (in_array($category->getParentId(), [Category::ROOT_CATEGORY_ID, Category::TREE_ROOT_ID])) {
            return '';
        }
        $path = $category->getUrlPath();
        if ($path !== null && !$category->dataHasChangedFor('url_key') && !$category->dataHasChangedFor('parent_id')) {
            return $path;
        }
        $path = $category->getUrlKey();
        if ($path === false) {
            return $category->getUrlPath();
        }

        return $path;
    }
```